# How to build optgroup with option from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JSON input:

```
[
  {
    "No Value in Support": [
      {
        "5": "In house support (HIS)"
      },
      {
        "6": "No interaction with support (NIS)"
      },
      {
        "7": "No value in SWR maintenance (NVS)"
      },
      {
        "8": "Support from other 3rd party (SOT)"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I am trying to build something like this:

```
<select id="sel" name="id">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

where the `label` of the `optgroup` is the `key` on the main array, the `value` of each `option` is the `key` on the subarray and the text is the value.

For example this is an expected output from the sample above:

```
<select id="sel" name="id">
  <optgroup label="No Value in Support">
    <option value="5">In house support (HIS)</option>
    <option value="6">No interaction with support (NIS)</option>
    <option value="7">No value in SWR maintenance (NVS)</option>
    <option value="8">Support from other 3rd party (SOT)</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
  var sel_content = '';

  $.each(data, function(idx, arr) {
    sel_content += '<optgroup label="' + idx + '">';
    $.each(arr, function(arr_idx, arr_value) {
      sel_content += '<option value="' + arr_idx + '">' + arr_value + '</option>';
    });
    sel_content += '</optgroup>';
  });

  $('#sel').append(sel_content);
```

But if you look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/y086oomp/1/) you'll see isn't working properly because I am getting Object as the values. Can any give me some help?

Comment: Does it have to abide by this JSON structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data accessing is not correct. You need to use iterators correctly to do it like following.

```js
var data = [{
    "No Value in Support": [{
      "5": "In house support (HIS)"
    }, {
      "6": "No interaction with support (NIS)"
    }, {
      "7": "No value in SWR maintenance (NVS)"
    }, {
      "8": "Support from other 3rd party (SOT)"
    }],
    "Not using Software": [{
      "9": "Business needs changed (BNC)"
    }, {
      "10": "Replaced by GE (RBG)"
    }, {
      "11": "Replaced by Iconics (RBI)"
    }, {
      "12": "Replaced by Others (RBO)"
    }, {
      "13": "Replaced by Rockwell (RBR)"
    }, {
      "14": "Replaced by Siemens (RBS)"
    }]
}];

var sel_content = '';

for (var key in data[0]) {
    sel_content = '<optgroup label="' + key + '">';
    data[0][key].forEach(function(item) {
        for (var prop in item) {
           sel_content += '<option value="' + prop + '">' + item[prop] + '</option>';
        }
    });
    sel_content += '</optgroup>';
    $('#sel').append(sel_content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel" name="id"></select>
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y086oomp/8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Since your JSON is such that it's a single item array of objects you have to change your code to be the first item of the array:

```
  var sel_content = '';

  $.each(data[0], function(idx, arr) {
    sel_content += '<optgroup label="' + idx + '">';
    $.each(arr[0], function(arr_idx, arr_value) {
      sel_content += '<option value="' + arr_idx + '">' + arr_value + '</option>';
    });
    sel_content += '</optgroup>';
  });

  $('#sel').append(sel_content);
```

Here is a fiddle of it working now: https://jsfiddle.net/y086oomp/4/

Answer (score 1):

Using pure jQuery:
// HTML

```
<select id="in"></select>
<button id="apply">APPLY</button>
```

// JavaScript

```
    var vbin = [
      {
        "No Value in Support": [
          {
            "5": "In house support (HIS)"
          },
          {
            "6": "No interaction with support (NIS)"
          },
          {
            "7": "No value in SWR maintenance (NVS)"
          },
          {
            "8": "Support from other 3rd party (SOT)"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    $("#apply").click(function() {
      $.each(vbin, function(idx, arr) {
        var $og = $("<optgroup></optgroup>");
        for (var k in arr) {
          $og.attr("label", k);
          $.each(arr[k], function(ai, av) {
            var $se = $("<option></option>");

            for (var ka in av) {
              $se.val(ka);
              $se.text(av[ka]);
            }

            $og.append($se);
          });
        }

        $("#in").append($og);
      });
    });
```

A little clunky because of the JSON structure, but it works.

Working pen: https://codepen.io/barrychapman/pen/WjLjMd